# VSFTPD Refusing Connection Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ftp

Trying to setup VSFTPD to use with ShareX for file and image uploading.

When checking on the status i get this

```
root@vps:~# /etc/init.d/vsftpd status
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-05-09 13:30:03 EDT; 3min 40s ago
  Process: 8232 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 8229 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8232 (code=exited, status=2)

May 09 13:30:03 vps systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
May 09 13:30:03 vps systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/...MENT
May 09 13:30:03 vps systemd[1]: Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

In ShareX when sending a test upload I get the error "No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed the contents of your `vsftpd.conf` file. Most likely, vsftpd isn't able to find an address to listen on. Adding/editing the following directives in `vsftpd.conf` should help:

```
listen=YES
listen_address=<your public IPv4 address>
```

See the vsftpd.conf official manpage for further info here http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html